# Clonning of tables from one database to another database in sql server 2008 using Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

My requirement: i need to create two databases say db1 & db2 on the same server,if we create a table in db1 then it should be created in db2.If we do any modifications like Update,delete,insert etc on columns of tables in db1 then it should be replicated in db2.It is like a clonning process.How can i solve this problem.Please explain the procedure.I'm using sql server 2008 with Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, SQL Server express cannot serve as a source for replication.

Depending on your requirements, you could:

1. Backup the database daily and restore to target server; you will of course lose all updates done on the target in between
2. Create log shipping (backup tlog, copy to target, restore tlog there)l database will have to be in full recovery model, and target database is read only
3. Write scripts for every change and apply it on both databases
4. Write your own routines to propagate the changes.

I'd recommend #3.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer.Can i know which version of visual studio supports Replication?

Comment: Visual Studio AFAIK uses Express (or LocalDb) edition of SQL Server, so replication is not part of the package. You need the **Developer** edition (I believe it's part of MSDN subs), or Standard/Enterprise, but they're for database servers, not for a developer machne.